# "Access is denied" while trying to retrieve Outlook tasks with Graph API

Tags: python, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have  an app registered in AzureAD, which I gave all Graph API permissions.
Yet when I try to get: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/[user id]/outlook/tasks

Or:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/events

I get "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again." error, but I have no more permissions I can add.
I used the administrator consent to allow all of the permission, but nothing changed.
(Other things in Graph beta API are working)

This is the code I use in Python:

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[domain]/oauth2/token"
data = {'client_id': '1111111111',
    'client_secret': '2222222222',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
access_token = r.json()['access_token']
data = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/[user id]/outlook/tasks"
r = requests.get(url, headers=data)
print r.content
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the permissions you added?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you're using a Service Principal? If so, where is your AD tenant ID?

Comment: AD tenant ID is here: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[domain/tenant id]/oauth2/token"

Comment: read all users full profile
read and write devices
read directory data
read all groups
read contacts in all mailboxes
read calendars in all mailboxes
read mail in all mailboxes
read all hidden memberships
read all usage reports

Comment: read and write files in all site collections
read files in all site collections
read all user mailbox settings
read and write domains
read all onenote notebooks
Delegated Permissions:
view users basic profile
view users email address
create, read, update and delete user tasks and projects
read user tasks
access users data anytime
sign users in
read items in all site collections
read all files that user can access
read user files
read user contacts
read user calendars
read user mail
access directory as the signed in user
read directory data

Comment: read all groups
read all users full profiles
read all users basic profiles
sign in and read user profile
read user and shared mail
read user and shared calendars
read user and shared contacts
read user and shred tasks
read all usage reports
have full access to the application’s folder
read files that the user selects
read user mailbox settings
read user one note notebooks
read all one note notebooks that user can access
read user devices
read and write user mailbox settings

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

'grant_type': 'client_credentials'

Application permissions not allowed

Delegate permissions are allowed

For more clarity refer to this : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

Comment: When answering a question, you're expected to add all the insights relevant to the question in your answer, rather than referring the asker to a website. You can surely provide an external link for more details, but the main concepts should be quoted in your answer.